# SQL Loader skips blank fields surrounded by \t if OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED is on

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to load data from a file to Oracle DB using

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    ID NUMBER(38) DEFAULT NULL,
    X VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
    NUM NUMBER(38) DEFAULT NULL,
    Y VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Data testdata.txt:

```
ID  X   NUM Y    
1   x1  0   y1
2   x2  0   "y2
."
3       0   y3
4       0   "y4
."
5   x5  0   y5
```

and written with tabs replaced with \t:

```
ID\tX\tNUM\tY    
1\tx1\t0\ty1
2\tx2\t0\t"y2
."
3\t \t0\ty3
4\t \t0\t"y4
."
5\tx5\t0\ty5
```

So it is important that lines 3 and 4 (counting header as 0) contain a field that is simply a SPACE and lines 2 and 4 contain a quoted field containing the line separator \n

Control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET we8iso8859p1
INFILE 'testdata.txt' "STR '\n'"
PRESERVE BLANKS
INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE
FIELDS CSV WITH EMBEDDED TERMINATED BY "\t" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
    ID,
    X,
    NUM,
    Y
)
```

Result:

```
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table TEST_TABLE, column Y.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
Record 4: Rejected - Error on table TEST_TABLE, column Y.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
```

What I tried:

Using | as field separator makes the data load correctly - unfortunately I don't control the data.

Removing the NUM column makes the problem go away - this is not an option.

Using TRAILING NULLCOLS hides the error and loads faulty data

Not using PRESERVE BLANKS does not solve the problem and also ruins data

Replacing \t with X'09' in the control file changes nothing

Not using CSV WITH EMBEDDED or OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED moves the problem to failing on the quoted fields

Using data types in controlfile does nothing

Using NULLIF X=BLANKS does not solve the problem and would ruin data if it did.

Question:

How do I make SQL Loader read fields containing only BLANKS in a data file with fields separated by TAB and optionally enclosed by '"'

Comment: You have fields that seems to have a \n in them (lines starting with 2 and 4). This leads to the errors you're seeing. It is not the fact that there are blanks. Are you sure that replacing tabs with |, without correcting for the \n fixes the error?

Comment: Yes, the combination of empty fields and tab separators and (wierdly) number fields and multi-line fields is the problem. Remove any one of those factors and it works. But I can't remove any of them.

Comment: sqlloader handles blank fields and numbers very well. The main issue I see is the multiline fields. Have a look [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=sql-loader-not-loading-if-column-value-in-multiple-lines-and-value-enclosed-in-double-quotes) for a possible solution.

Comment: No, the problems seems to be [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-658D9A9E-41A9-4BD7-BDD6-81B5A2ACC025): "... SQL*Loader scans past all whitespace at the end of the previous field until it finds a nonblank, nontab character." Which is an issue if your delimiter is a tab. I can't see a way around that though, other than preprocessing the file. Even then, "Using | as field separator makes the data load correctly" - are you sure? I think X ends up null for those rows, not a single space, for the same reason.

Comment: @AlexPoole I just checked, and the spaces are loaded correctly into the DB when separator is |

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right... it normally would lose them but you already have `PRESERVE BLANKS`. So you could pre-process the data file to change tabs to pipes; but carefully if the enclosed fields can have embedded tabs as well as new lines. Not ideal...

Comment: Yeah, that is my backup plan. What a weird bug to run into.